# Не работает exclude-from-classmap

Tags: php, laravel, composer

Пытаюсь перезаписать класс библиотеки из vendor

```
"autoload": {
    "exclude-from-classmap": [
        "VladimirYuldashev\\LaravelQueueRabbitMQ\\Queue\\RabbitMQQueue"
    ],
    "files": [
        "app/Queue/RabbitMQQueue.php"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
        "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
        "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
    }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "exclude-from-classmap": [
        "VladimirYuldashev\\LaravelQueueRabbitMQ\\Queue\\RabbitMQQueue"
    ],
    "files": [
        "app/Queue/RabbitMQQueue.php"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
},
```

Затем запускаю composer dump-autoload -o. Но не пишется ни composer.lock, не исключается класс из autoload_classmap.php. Туда добавляется новый класс (неймспейс тотже что и у старого), он подключается, но заменяется старым. Подскажите, как быть?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил с помощью установки вот этих настроек PHPStorm
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

PhpStorm никогда не принимал classmap во exclude-from-classmap внимание записи composer.json.
В настоящее время я бы предложил щелкнуть правой кнопкой мыши config.example.php и выбрать «Переопределить тип файла»> «Обычный текст».